# ActionbarSherlock SearchView in menu.xml gives Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

When I try to add an ActionbarSherlock `SearchView` to my ActionBar the application crashes as soon as the activity should be shown. As reason for this, I found the following in LogCat:

```
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873): Cannot instantiate class: com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView
...
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873):  ... 32 more
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01001f a=-1}
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2035)
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:342)
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:768)
10-22 21:22:51.070: W/MenuInflater(21873):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:442)
```

When I use the regular `android.widget.SearchView` for the `android:actionViewClass` everything works fine.
I followed the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) from the Android website.

This is my menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_add_page"
        android:title="@string/menu_add_page"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And this is the relevant code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_overview, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

Is this a (known) bug, or am I missing something else here?

Comment: `SearchView` in `ActionbarSherlock` is/was a known issue. The `dev` branch contains the support, however it is not complete and seems they are still having issues with Suggestions. See [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/70#issuecomment-7913573) and [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/659) for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SearchView` in `ActionbarSherlock` is / was a known issue. The `dev` branch contains the support, however it is not complete and seems they are still having issues with Suggestions.

See [github here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/70#issuecomment-7913573) and [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/659) for reference.

Here is a link to the `ActionBarSherlock` > `SearchView` [Source](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/dev/library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/widget/SearchView.java)

Comment: SearchView was included in ABS 4.2, but this particular bug is here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685

Answer (score 3):

This issue is caused by the lack of certain attributes in v-14 version of Sherlock Theme.

I fixed it by adding

```
<item name="textColorPrimary">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_light</item>
<item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_dark</item>
```

to the Sherlock theme and it runs beautifully again. Not sure if ideal solution but for now it works :)

Comment: Hi, where are you adding it exactly? I tried on abs__themes.xml but it didn't work. Thank you!!!

Comment: Try debugging to see where your actual problem is. Mine crash when inflating the **TextView** in the ActionBar. Checking the source code it's referencing **textColorPrimary**. So I add them into the root theme and it's fixed for me.

Comment: Yes, it was there. Thank you very much for the hint!

Comment: According to Jake Wharton, creator of ActionBarSherlock. We are supposed to use Theme context when working with SearchView. That way it works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

As *hahnjo* mentioned [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685):

> If you use the theme `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` and create the view with `new SearchView(this)`, it won't work...
>   Combinations that will work:
>   `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` with `new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext())`
>   `Theme.Sherlock.Light` or `Theme.Sherlock.Light` with `new SearchView(this)`

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error, however it was because I wasn't setting the `android:theme` on the `<application>` node in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Once I set `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` on the `<application>` node, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to do all of the following to get this to work:

Ensure the application theme was set in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<application
        android:name="com.xxx.MyApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

I added the "missing" settings to the base style:

```
<style>
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="searchDropdownBackground">@drawable/abs__search_dropdown_dark</item>
    <item name="searchViewTextField">@drawable/abs__textfield_searchview_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="searchViewTextFieldRight">@drawable/abs__textfield_searchview_right_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/abs__ic_clear</item>
    <item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/abs__ic_search</item>
    <item name="searchViewGoIcon">@drawable/abs__ic_go</item>
    <item name="searchViewVoiceIcon">@drawable/abs__ic_voice_search</item>
    <item name="searchAutoCompleteTextView">@style/Widget.Sherlock.SearchAutoCompleteTextView</item>
 </style>
```

Then updated my Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu() to pass a "themed context" to the menu inflater like:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)
{
    final MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this.getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    this.initSearchView(menu);
    return true;
}
```

Then passed the same themed context into the SearchView creation/initialization:

```
private void initSearchView(final Menu menu)
{
    final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final MenuItem searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

    final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(this.getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(this.getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(final View v, final boolean hasFocus)
        {
            if (!hasFocus)
            {
                // Collapse the searchbox on ActionBar
                searchViewMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this helps someone or it gets "fixed" so that is just works.